Where should an application's admin tools be located?
I am trying to make some admin and management tools to help staff/moderators manage users and content in an online application. But how will staff access the management tools?
There are two options:

Subdirectory: Place it in example.com/support and show management tools if the user is internal staff or just general help information to an external user
Subdomain/microservice: Place it in its own microservice app and access it via a subdomain of support.example.com or somewhere else entirely (which will be locked down to internal staff only)

If I go for the microservice approach then that means having a new web project with its own development and deployment cycle and SSL security etc.
The subdirectory option is easier to do, but is it acceptable practice to have back-office tools located within the app itself?
The minimum requirement is that both manangement tools and the standard users will share the same database.

This is not an architecture question, nor one of design patterns. There is no single objective answer here. This question is not meaningfully answerable except as a "list all ways you could do this", which is both off-topic as a list question and shows no effort on the part of the poster as to what has been attempted and what the requirements arE.

@Flater what effort are you expecting to see when this is a design question? the minimum requirement is a secure location for back-office management tools. but i cannot see another app that has them as a subdirectory. X.com probably uses something like admin.x.com

Your focus on "subdirectory" indicates that you believe the URL is directly indicative of how the underlying application(s) is/are hosted. It's not. You're trying to tackle this from the wrong end. Work from your requirements outwards (or start from a suggested approach), instead of asking for context-free pro and con lists for every approach that you can think of might be used in existing applications.

@Flater yes I agree. it did make me edit the question because a minimum requirement is that both the user-facing app and management tools share the same database

Still the same problem. Having the same database says nothing about how the applications are hosted. This question can't be answered when the only given premise is built on misunderstandings.

Whether you place this in a subdirectory or another domain is irrelevant. I've worked on applications that did either way and it works fine. The important thing with admin tools is to ensure you properly authenticate and authorize each request. Once you do that, it doesn't matter where you put the admin tools.
If there is any "acceptable practice" it is to authenticate users. If you do that and prevent unauthorized access to these tools (a permission denied page is perfectly acceptable and honest) then structure these admin tools to make it easier on you to maintain this.
Further reading:

Zero Trust Architecture, National Institute of Standards and Technology, US Department of Commerce (https://nist.gov)
Zero trust security model, Wikipedia


Are there are any pros and cons to either approach of subdirectory vs self-contained app (on a subdomain or somewhere else entirely)

@volumeone, that would make this question too broad for the Q&A format of this community. You have asked a very general question for which I can only provide a very general answer. If you edit your post, be sure not to invalidate existing answers. If an edit would invalidate answers, then post a new question.
